# How do i show each user who has commented in a topic

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to show the avatar of each user who has commented in a topic. I pretty much have a Topic Model and a Comment Model. In my index page i have a list of all the topics created and a list of avatar of the user who commented but it only gets the list of the first topic and the images get repeated.

This is what i have in my index but I end up getting the avatar of each comment with repeated images.

```
   <tbody>
        <% @topics.each do |topic| %>
            <th class="topic"> <%= link_to topic.title, topic %> </th>
            <th class="category"><%= topic.category.title %></th>
            <th class="users"><%= image_tag topic.user.avatar.url(:thumb)%></th>
            <th class="replies"><%= topic.comments.count %> </th>
            <th class="replies"></th>
            <th class="activities"></th>
            <% @comment.each do |comment| %>
                <%= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url(:thumb)  %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
```

My comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @topics = Topic.all
    @comments = Comment.includes(:user)
end

def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id 
    @comment.save
    redirect_to @commentable
end


private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are displaying the user of only one comment.

```
<% @comment.each do |comment| %>
```

You probably need to get all comments of the topic instead. See below.

```
<% topic.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

To avoid `N+1` issue, you can eager load the comments too

```
def index
  @topics = Topic.includes(:comments => :user)
end
```

To display unique users, you can use [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq) with a block.
Assuming comments table has `user_id`, as foreign key,

```
<% topic.comments.uniq(&:user_id).each do |comment| %>
```

Comment: That works perfect just for one thing. I don't want to keep displaying the same user if that person has multiple comments. Just one image if that user commented.